# How to Count 'Present' Instances in Lesson1 for the Current Date in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to count how many time have present or Absent in Lesson1 in this day or current date

I tray this code but i don't know how can i have it in current day.

```
    SELECT TOP (1000) [Attendance_ID]
      ,[Attendance_Date]
      ,[Lesson_1]
      ,[Lesson_2]
      ,[Lesson_3]
      ,[Lesson_4]
      ,[Lesson_5]
      ,[Lesson_6]
      ,[Remark]
      ,[Student_ID]
      FROM [Attendance_Management_System].[dbo].[Attendance_Table]

  select count(*) FROM Attendance_Table where  Lesson_1='Present'
```

[image]

Comment: Not a C# query.. Please use only relevant tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `GETDATE()` function to get the current date.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS CountPresent
FROM Attendance_Table
WHERE Lesson_1 IN ('Present')
  AND Attendance_Date = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);
```